# docker: official ubuntu 14.04 image

Tags: containers, docker

I try to find the official Ubuntu 14.04 image:

```
docker search ubuntu | grep -i offi
```

But I only find this image, which I would trust:

```
ubuntu    Official Ubuntu base image
```

The other images are from unknown sources (like foouser/ubuntu...) , and I don't trust these sources.

Comment: https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The one you found is the one you want. Just use the 14.04/trusty tag:

```
docker run -it ubuntu:trusty /bin/bash
```